# How should private airports or locations not regularly intended for landing be identified if you land at or take off from them?

Tags: airport, logging

How are runways on sectional charts that are listed as private identified?

Lets say I fly from a public airport to a private strip; I would log the departure airport as BNA, but what would I list the private strip as?

Generally, what is the accepted norm?

Comment: Is this US specific? Or are you interested in general/ICAO conventions?

Comment: Where are you logging this?  Pilot log book, booking out at the departure airport, flight plan?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the FAA determine which format of location identifier to assign to an airport?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/34228/how-does-the-faa-determine-which-format-of-location-identifier-to-assign-to-an-a)

Comment: @Lady_A I'm not asking how the identification of airports are determined when they're named, I am asking what you log an airport as in a logbook if it has no identifier on a sectional chart and is not included in an AF/D.

Comment: @DaveGremlin Pilot logbook.

Comment: @Jamiec I am not concerned with whether it is FAA/ICAO.  Answers for one or both are still value-added I think.

Comment: In EASA land, for my log book, I just use names.  For example Old Warden to Little Snoring (both are unlicenced private fields).  I record my first visit to an airfield on a separate page and that includes the IACO code if there is one

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the USA, as far as your logbook is concerned, FAR 61.51(b)(1)(iii) only requires "Location where the aircraft departed and arrived," not the 4-letter ICAO identifier of your airports. When you abbreviate the airport with its identifier, that's all you're doing: abbreviating. You could, for instance, write "Nashville International Airport" instead of "KBNA."

Seaplane and helicopter pilots often land in places that aren't even airports. You might log the destination as "Murphy Lake" or "Walmart Parking Lot." Such is the standard convention.

For purposes of the flight plan, there are a few options if flying to a location that has no identifier. On an ICAO flight plan to a location with no identifier, you would enter ZZZZ as your airport, and in the remarks section include a DEST/ group including the lat/long of your destination. For instance, I think DEST/3607N08641W would work. On an FAA flight plan, you can list the nearest waypoint to your destination, and again, describe your actual destination as a common name or lat/long in the remarks.

Comment: Those of us with wheels on our planes have also been known to land in places that aren't airports, e.g. dry lake beds.  And FWIW, I don't think I've ever used those 3/4 letter codes in my logbook, if for no other reason than that if I look back in it, I'd like to know what place(s) the logbook entries refer to without having to look up the codes.

Comment: @Dave-CFII I think you bring up a great missed point here.  There are tons of "non-airport" destinations for perfectly legal operations which clearly kills any idea that you must log an airport much less an ID.

Comment: Ditto to above. It's fun to land on roads.  Log every landing!

Answer (score 3):

I would use the airport identifier, if available, or the name on the sectional.
For example, on this section of NY sectional, you can see several (Pvt) airports, they are indicated by red R in a circle.
PASPORT is enterable in skyvector.com as a destination, as is WATERS.  Entering them as a destination, skyvector will change them to an airport identifier, which you can then type in as a waypoint.

B&B, just north of PASPORT, can't be entered as anything I could find to start. 
But, dragging the pink route line, it can be pulled over B&B and then it shows up with an identifier you can use.  Same with the Unknown airport south of 9B1.

If you click on the Departure or Destination airport, skyvector will open more info for that airport, and from there a list of all airports and their identifiers in the state can be selected.  B&B and Unknown are both listed there.
[image]

Comment: You can also put the name into Airnav and get the identifier that way.

Comment: Huh - I would have thought "unknown" would either have tons of matches, or been unrecognized - yet there it is, 1MA5 in Southborough, MA.

Comment: Whoever named 1MA5 as "Unknown Field" must have had a weird sense of humor.

Comment: One of the pilots from 9B1 created that strip, he was a former airline pilot I believe. Passed away a few years ago.  I think the runway might be a road in a housing development now.

Comment: @CrossRoads In southern Florida, on the northern shore of Lake Okeechobee there is Okeechobee CO (OBE) airport, and just to northeast of that there is a private (maybe not) one labeled as "Objectionable", but has no "(Pvt)" label.

Comment: Interesting name.  Pvt label appears to be missing, but the 'behind the scenes' info shows Sunniland Ranch is Private use: https://skyvector.com/airport/08FD/Sunniland-Ranch-Airport   There are quite a few private airfields in that area!

Comment: @RyanMortensen "Objectionable" is something different and worth its own question.

Comment: Ditto to above.  It's fun to land on roads!  Log every landing.  Ditto for those sailplane outlandings.  If you are staying near an airport, you aren't really trying.  It's a fine thing to be objectionable.